# Eclipse Juno vs Neon War File Sizes

Tags: java, eclipse, war, eclipse-juno, eclipse-neon

I have a project that was done in Eclipse Juno for Apache Tomcat 6. I have moved that project to Neon for Apache Tomcat 8 and found that when exporting the war file - it is twice as large via Neon vs Juno.  I have it set to do NOT include source files in both.

My question is, is this normal?  I haven't found any options I might have missed regarding the War file. At best, all I can see is whether or not to include the source.  I'm just wondering if I am missing something or if that is normal and I shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Technology is moving, So is encryption

Comment: You have **two** variables in your equation. If you are really curious what is going on, I would try to generate that Tomcat 6 WAR using the newer eclipse, too. And in case ... what would it help? In the end: you want to move to Tomcat 8 probably, and you also want to upgrade your eclipse setup regularly. So there is not much point besides biting the bullet ...

Comment: If you want to see what's different, you can get a list of the files in each war and compare the two. if you're on linux, you can do something like unzip -l war1.war >war1.out then unzip -l war2.war >war2.out then diff war1.out war2.out and that will show you what's different

Comment: You were correct here, Brian. Turns out the project I had pulled into Neon (which I had originally done in Juno) was loaded with SVN files. I hadn't added the SVN plugin to Neon yet which resulted in them being in the WAR file. Once I added the SVN plugin, Eclipse then removed those files from my War and everything dropped back to normal sizes. Appreciated the feedback which led me to my "doh!" moment!